# Why doesn't the C#/VB.NET compiler allow classes to be derived from System.MulticastDelegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, clr

What was the rationale behind prohibiting users from inheriting from System.MulticastDelegate?

Comment: What is the use case for inheriting from `MulticastDelegate`? I can't imagine one.

Comment: A sample use case for inheriting from MulticastDelegate is event interception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MulticastDelegate` is only meant for the compilers themselves to create delegate types, which all derive from `MulticastDelegate`. It is **not** meant to be subclassed by users. This is similar to `System.ValueType` which is only meant for implementing `struct` types.